# "And" or "or" omitted in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

In the following sentence, is it correct to assume that “**and**” or “**or**” is omitted before “through our online services”? If so, is such an omission grammatically acceptable, or is it just an error by the writer?

> This Privacy Policy describes why and how we process the personal data we receive over our websites, through software and applications, through our online services, when we provide services, when we license our products, when we handle inquiries about our products and any other means, such as, when we obtain your data at an exhibition.

Answer (score 2):

No, I think it's not missing there because the list isn't done yet. It's quite an unwieldy list and impractical to parse, but it isn't really intended to be readable but to be legally solid. I believe the intent is:

> This Privacy Policy describes why and how we process the personal data we receive...
>
> - over our websites,
> - through software and applications,
> - through our online services,
> - when we provide services,
> - when we license our products,
> - when we handle inquiries about our products
> - **and** any other means, such as, when we obtain your data at an exhibition.

In other words, "every conceivable way we could think of that we might come by your data, and also any way we haven't thought of yet."

Comment: Thanks! So, all listed items relate to "receive", not "process", right?

Comment: @user442266 Good heavens, I can't imagine any way of having them modify "process." No, all the list items are ways that they "receive" data. If there's an error, it's that the final item needs "and *by* any other means."